# AWS restrict access to subfolder in s3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to restrict an IAM role to only be able to access a specific subfolder (key prefix) in an S3 bucket. Here's the policy JSON I'm using, but currently the user can still access other folders in the bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::somebucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::somebucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:ListBucketByTags",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/datasets/company1/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Currently, using this role I can still do, e.g.

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/datasets/company2/dataset.csv
```

and download the dataset. What am I doing wrong?

When I try and simulate the policy it seems to be correct (trying to getObject on `mybucket/datasets/company2/dataset.csv` fails implicitly, but this does not happen in practice. There are no other policies attached to this user.

Comment: Is there a Bucket Policy on `mybucket`? Something _must_ be granting the access. If you delete the above policies, can the user still access `dataset.csv`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43719257/grant-access-to-read-a-subdirectory-within-an-amazon-s3-bucket